# Design rf trace antenna 433MHz + 315MHz on pcb

Tags: antenna, eaglecad, trace, 433mhz

I'm a hobbyist and I'm designing a PCB in Eagle that include micro controller and RF receiver and transmitter, 2 modules of 433mhz and 2 of 315mhz,

I have a defined place on the PCB of 10x50 mm for the 433mhz antenna, and another 10x50mm for the 315mhz.

I searched the entire web and could not find a design,
I created a simple doodle of antenna (i have no experience in antenna design... and this might be horribly wrong)

So this question is for the experienced ones out there:

**How should a 433mhz trace antenna look like in 10x50mm space?**

**How should a 315mhz trace antenna look like in 10x50mm space?**

I uploaded a picture of what i got so far.
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Texas Instruments has an excellent [application node](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra161b/swra161b.pdf) on antenna design. 
Antenna design from scratch is not a trivial exercise and if you don't have experience or access to expensive modeling software, you'd be best using a proven reference design. There are probably countless other reference designs for a 433Mhz and 315Mhz PCB antenna. Be careful though, a multi-antenna system can be a completely different beast than a single antenna system.

Comment: Also, check Eagle's public libraries. Someone has probably already created a trace antenna as a footprint that you can drop in. I know I found a 2.4 GHz antenna several years ago in a lib on the Eagle public lib page.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm loosing my mind, I searched EVERYWHERE and did not find a single library of antennas no 433mhz and no 315mhz, i did found some 2.4ghz... but it's no good for me... This is so weird because 433+315 are so commonly used...
ALSO: where is this public lib page? https://cadsoft.io/resources/libraries/ no results there...

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this information will be helpful.

Search Engine for EAGLE Libraries
http://www.diymodules.org/eagle-search?text=315+MHZ+PCB+antenna&type=dev%2Cpkg%2Csym&lib=usr%2Cstd

PCB Antenna Reference Designs
http://hackaday.com/2014/02/28/pcb-antenna-reference-designs/

I had more links but can not post them due to low reputation. If you need more ask and maybe I can post more in a different reply.

Comment: nope... those links do not help... actually i found at ti website a evolution board for 433mhz chip with pcb antenna, and the provided a gerber files, so i importand the copper layers from them (i'ts a top  to bottem lines using vias, hili antanna)... and i did the same for 315mhz i found gerber files online for same kind of antenna... check this out: http://www.ti.com/tool/cc11xlemk-433